# How can I make a button with an svg inside interactive when clicking on it?

Tags: javascript, button, click

I want a button to change to an active state when the user is clicking on it. The function of this row of buttons is scrolling to a part of the content when clicking on the button. I managed to add a new color to the svg when hovering over it. Now I want to have it changed color when clicking on it.

[image: 1]

```
 <div id="myDIV">
                        <button class="btn"> 
                            <svg width="104" height="10" viewBox="0 0 104 10" fill="none"      
                        xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg">
                                <rect width="104" height="10" rx="5" fill="white"/>
                            </svg>
                        </button> 

                        <button class="btn active"> 
                            <svg width="104" height="10" viewBox="0 0 104 10" fill="none"   
                          xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg">
                                <rect width="104" height="10" rx="5" fill="white"/>
                            </svg>
                        </button> 
                
                        <button class="btn"> 
                            <svg width="104" height="10" viewBox="0 0 104 10" fill="none"  
                           xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg">
                                <rect width="104" height="10" rx="5" fill="white"/>
                            </svg>
                        </button> 
                  
                        <button class="btn"> 
                            <svg width="104" height="10" viewBox="0 0 104 10" fill="none" 
                        xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg">
                                <rect width="104" height="10" rx="5" fill="white"/>
                            </svg>
                        </button> 
                  
            </div>
```

This is the CSS

```
 #myDIV {
display: flex;
position: relative;
bottom: -320px;
}
.scrollbar_nav_list {
  display:flex;
  justify-content:center;
  gap:1rem;
}

.btn {
  border: none;
  cursor: pointer;
  outline: none;
}

.active, .btn :hover {
  fill: #FB9DA0;
}
```

I tried to put some JavaScript code to make the button change color when activating it by clicking. I referred to a div with IdName and used classes to refer to the buttons. It actually resulted in nothing different: no change of color when clicking on the buttons with the svgs inside.

```
    <script>
        var header = document.getElementById("myDIV");
        var btns = header.getElementsByClassName("btn");
        for (var i = 0; i < btns.length; i++) {
        btns[i].addEventListener("click", function() {
        var current = document.getElementsByClassName("active");
        current[0].className = current[0].className.replace(" active", "");
        this.className += " active";
        });
        }
    </script>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
.active, .btn :hover {
  fill: #FB9DA0;
}
```

This rule selects the `button` elements in the markup, but you need to set the `fill` value of the `rect` elements inside the buttons’ `svg` elements. Try this instead.

```
.active svg rect, .btn svg rect:hover {
    fill: #FB9DA0;
}
```

Comment: Wow @Padeso, it works immediately! So glad, thanks a million :) So it doesn't matter that the JavaScript code is not targetting this <rect> element?

Comment: There are lots of ways it could be done, as long as the CSS rule affects the correct element.

Comment: Great. Perhaps you feel like looking at the next step as well? I added horizontal scrolling content for the buttons to jump to. The jumping is not working out that well :') https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75472422/how-can-i-create-a-jump-that-moves-to-the-right-place-inside-a-horizontal-scroll